# What does the -p and -s mean in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing shell script, and I have a few questions about some of the symbols and conditions.

What does 
    -p and -s mean as conditions in shell script?

Comment: Can you give us some bit of code? That would be helpful to know what you're talking about. For example, are you talking about `bash -p` or `if [[ -p ... ]]`? Or, is it in some other piece of code such as `read -p`?

Comment: @Mawg says reinstate Monica google literally does not tell anything if you search for "shell script -p", this question is the first result. I don't know why you guys downvoted him into oblivion...

Comment: I did not downvote (I only very rarely do). But I did wonder if he had read the man pages & could explain which part was not clear. Also, this question cannot possibly answered unless we know ***which*** shell (and, it might get a better answer on our [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash builtin conditionals (double square brackets), then look in the manual for [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), under the section "Conditional Expressions".

If you are using the sh conditionals (single square brackets), then look in the manual for [test(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

They'll both say the same in this case, though:

**-p** *file*
      True if file exists and is a named pipe (FIFO).

**-s** *file*
      True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.